# Ace editor: redefinition of 'name' warning

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I'm using Ace Editor on a site. I noticed that, if I write  a statement like

`var name = "Homer Simpson";`

it gives me the warning: `Redefinition of 'name'`. This behavior can also be observed [on their site](http://ace.c9.io/) by copying the above statement. Is there any quick fix to this problem?

Comment: Is this global scope? `window.name` has meaning https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.name

Comment: Oh, it seems like that's the problem then. I will be running my code as a web worker so I don't think it will affect `window.name`, however the editor probably does its check in the global scope.

Comment: Yah it's just a warning.. >.>

Comment: @EricG It's just a warning, yes. But the site is aimed to teach programming for beginners (teenagers), and I don't want them to feel intimidated by a warning over something that's quite difficult to explain for them at this stage. I guess I will have to rename the variable then

Comment: @pg-robban May I ask what the site is?

Comment: @YousifAl-Y It was a site I made for my master thesis, it's not available online anymore.

Comment: Hi, has anyone found a solution to this problem?